# Most efficient sorting algorithm for a short list

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following task:

Using Python, write a function to sort the following list of numbers from smallest to largest, and return a list.
65,78,-90,33,45,60,1,0,-6

I realise that there are many sorting algorithms out there, and as such I was wondering if there was a something like a standard one which is used across the board, perhaps due to highest efficiency, etc? Or would the selection of a sorting algorithm be more situationally dependent, and if so, is there a go-to for sorting within python lists?

Many thanks

Comment: I think the go-to for sorting within python lists is `sorted()` or `some_list.sort()` depending on whether or not you want to sort in place.

Comment: Your probably never going to beat the built-in `sorted` and `list.sort`, they use an adaptive merge sort, Tomorrow, which is highly optimized to handle various types of inputs. Also, it is implemented in C, so the constant factors will be much lower to boot

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga did something helpfully autocorrect "Timsort" for you?  Never heard of "Tomorrow".

Comment: @MarkRansom ugh, yes, I meant **Timsort**

Answer (score 1):

The go-tos for sorting Python lists are the built-in `sort()`/`sorted()` functions.  There's not really a point in writing a function that just calls `sorted()`, but here's what it would look like:

```
def pointless_sort(numbers):
    """Returns a sorted copy of the input list."""
    return sorted(numbers)

pointless_sort([65,78,-90,33,45,60,1,0,-6])
```

Since the task asks you to write a function that sorts only a *specific* list of numbers, though, the optimal implementation is to hardcode the solution; this will run in O(1) time, rather than O(n log n) time.

```
def optimal_but_highly_specific_sort():
    """Returns a sorted copy of [65,78,-90,33,45,60,1,0,-6] in O(1) time."""
    return [-90, -6, 0, 1, 33, 45, 60, 65, 78]
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends as there are multiple sorting algorithms - in Python underneath sort(ed) is TimSort - check it out on video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MsTNqK3o_w&t=2234s
It's algorithm that meets vast majority of requirements like stability, plus it great choice on average due to it's characteristics, cpu / memory complexity etc. but again on average.

As for sorting list of numbers that you've provided, which has only very small (absolute) values, much like someone's age for example, you could consider slightly modifying counting sort: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/

There's chance that you'll miss some crucial optimizations and due to memory management in Python you'd be better off implementing this in Cython or using default TimSort, but it might be worth giving it a try plus it's good excercise